# Selenium Set Menu

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to write a Python script with Selenium to use a webpage and I can't get .click() to select a expandable list. I've been able to login, navigate to the correct page, but then a list shows up and every element I've tried fails.

The div i'm trying to select is a tree. A list of settings options, you click it, it expands with more options, you click one of those, it opens a forum to fill out and save.

Here's the general layout of the list.

```
<li category="category">
      <a class="class">
            <i class="set-menu-icon"></i>
            <span class="set-menu-label" t="Settings">sectionOfTheSettings</span>
       </a>
       <ul style="display: none;">

          <li class="set-item" filename="someFile">
              <i class="set-item-icon"></i>
              <span class="set-menu-label" t="subSectionOfSettings">TCP/IP</span>
          </li>
```

After you click the section that you want to expand the HTML code changes to this: **class="set-item set-item-current"**

Here's my current Python script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "generic IP"

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("login").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("login").send_keys('gen')
driver.find_element_by_id("pswd").send_keys('generic')
driver.find_element_by_class_name("login-button").click()
#Change password prompt opens. Wait until visible and Close to bypass change
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "close")))
driver.find_element_by_id("close").click()
#Navigate to the settings page
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Setting").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) #wait for everything to load
```

I've tried using find_element_by_class,css_selector,and xpath with no success. 
I've tried choosing various elements to .click() some will be recognized with no errors but they won't actually do anything. Others error out and say that the element doesn't exist.

I'm likely just misunderstanding how the webpage works, I'm not very well educated on Javascript and Jquery which this page is relying on heavily. The page is supplied by an IoT device running on my local network.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using Katalon IDE and watching what xpaths it selected. Turns out I wasn't too far off and had actually gotten to work a few times. If nothing is changed on the settings form that appears it reverts back to the preview section.

Solution, Use IDE and export as Python. Edit script as needed.